# C++: Overloading var arg function

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic

Using g++.
I want the following code to compile without any warnings.

```
void f(const char* b)
{
  std::cout<<"char* called"<<std::endl;
}

void f(const char* format,...)
{
  std::cout<<"char*,... called"<<std::endl;
}

f("hello");
f("hello",1);
```

An error comes during compilation. Ambiguous call. Seems compiler can't distinguish between these two functions. But when i define second function like this:

```
void f(char* format,...)
{
  std::cout<<"char*,... called"<<std::endl;
}
```

It compiles but with the warning
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*

const can't be used to overload a function but it is still affects.
What is happening here?

Comment: Is the signature of the second "fix" correct, surely that should be `const char*`? If you call the above as `f("Hello %s")` this is not valid..

Comment: When you do `f("hello")`, which function should be called? Both alternatives (in your first version) are equally possible.

Comment: Contrary to what you say, pointer to const or non-const can be used to differentiate overloads.

Comment: I want to call f(const char* b) function. But the problem is that f(cosnt char* format,...) can also be called and that's strange.

Comment: _Why_ do you need to overload this? It seems to me that _either_ the second function should do what the first one does when given no arguments, in which case you can get away with a single implementation which works whether `va_args` is empty or not, _or_ the second will have a completely different implementation in which case it should maybe not have the same name.

Comment: It's *not* strange. Think about the standard C `printf` function, it can be called just fine with just a simple string argument and nothing else. The ellipsis means that the following arguments are *optional*.

Comment: You can use `templates`: [ideone](https://ideone.com/QnKaw8).

Comment: Ok. I understand that both functions can be called. But when i remove const (the second example) why it is compiles. And correct functions are called?

Comment: Because when you remove `const`, you have two completely different signatures: one taking a `char*` and one taking a `const char*` plus possibly more arguments. The literal string `"hello"` is normally a `const char*` but apparently your compiler is also allowed to consider it as a (non-`const`) `char*` although it should and does warn you about this. You'd have to look up the exact rules on overload resolution for your compiler but I would say it would be as much - if not more - in its right to call the `const char*` version as it does not require a `const`-to-non-`const` conversion.

Comment: I think @erip's answer would be the smartest choice for your case. Because the error that the compiler generates clearly means that for you first call `f("hello");` the two available methods match with the same priority. But with C++, a function template has always a lower priority over a specific definition.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The non-variadic function should be called. `...` conversion has the lowest rank, hence `char const*` function is better.

Comment: To make a type safe version youi might want to check out the Wikipedia example for variadic template `printf`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

Comment: Thank to you all for an answers. Templates are a good idea. But i decided to leave one fnuction with vararg. Because they both do the same thing like CompuChip said.